# Highlighting and Toggling between links - How to set the default class

Tags: jquery

Good day everyone!

I have this piece of code I am trying to get to work.
I have been searching this forum, came pretty close but can get it.

I am trying to toggle between links to highlight the current link.

This has been discussed on here, however I can't seem to find a solution that matches my problem.

I manage to get the link to toggle, add class and remove class.

What I am confused about is how do I assigned a default class.

Meaning I would like to give the links a default style, then override it with the add/remove class toggle.

Currently the links are not styled on default, if I style them directly with CSS, then the script does not work. That's because I cannot find a way to remove that style.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#test a").click(function () {
      $(".normal").removeClass("normal");
      $(this).toggleClass('normal');
    });
 });
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="test">
<a href="#">Testing</a>
<a href="#">Testing</a>
<a href="#">Testing</a>
</div>
```

The Solution:
To make this work I simply placed **CSS !important declaration** on the style I want to override. Because the default style is place directly on the selector, it does not allow any other style to take over. Meaning, If you apply two styles to one element, the direct style takes the charge.

CSS

```
.active{/*SETS THE ACTIVE STYLE*/
    color: #333 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#test a{ /*SETS THE DEFAULT STYLE*/
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

The JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#test a").click(function () {
      $(".normal").removeClass("active");
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
 });
```

The HTML:

```
    <div id="test">
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it with plain old css :)

```
<a href="#" class="foo">Testing</a>
```

That will give each one a default class.

**EDIT** just re-read your question, still use the CSS and then if you do something like:

```
$("a").removeClass();
```

It should remove all classes.

Comment: I tried that, but because the class is directly applied to the html element, I cannot toggle the classes. Basically what I need is for the default to be removed when a link is click to only highlight a single active link. The links are not going anywhere.

Comment: Thanks again - if you look at the code, the page loads with the normal style, I have the style directly on the elements. So the toggling does not work. Even with the remove class. The only way I can get it to work is if I have no style directly on the elements.

Comment: The only other thing I would try (I'm probably mis-understanding you) is to after $(document).ready... I would add $("a").addClass("foo");  Or however you want to specify the selector.  This will add it with jQuery and might work.  But I also don't see a reason why my way isn't working.  Can you maybe put your example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and see if it reproduces the problem.  If it does save it and post a link here so I can get a better understanding.

Comment: I tried it on there but getting mixed results. The toggling works fine, the problem is I cannot set a default style for the links. Back to hair pulling!

Comment: Yup no problem, glad you got it figured out :) Also don't forget to mark this as solved (there should be some checks below the arrows on the left of my answer.  This makes it easier for people looking for solutions :)